# Vue3 Composition API, how to get data from service?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm experimenting with the Composition API with Vue3. But there were some points I couldn't find. The same code did not work in two different projects.

What I want to do in my own project is to take the data through the API and use it according to what is required. In short, do the necessary get/post operations. I got this API from Vue's own example.

**This is the first project code, package.json and error message**

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <div v-for="datas in data" :key="datas.description">
      {{ datas.description }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";
import axios from "axios";
import { ref } from "vue";

@Options({
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
})
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  setup() {
    let data = ref([]);
    axios
      .get("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
      .then((res) => {
        data.value = res.data.bpi;
      });
  }
}
</script>

{
  "name": "api-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

[Vue warn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9U2X.png)

**This is the second project code, package.json, and data**

```
<template>
  <div v-for="datas in data" :key="datas.description">
    {{ datas.description }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import axios from "axios";
import { ref } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  setup() {
    let data = ref([]);
    axios.get("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json").then((res) => {
      data.value = res.data.bpi;
    });

    return {
      data,
    };
  },
}
</script>

{
  "name": "test-api",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

[my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWzFu.png)

Could there be an error in my Composition API usage?  I've heard that in some videos, "then" is not used for the Composition API. But that's the only way I was able to pull the data from the API.

If my solution is wrong, what method should it be, I'm new at Vuejs can you help?

Comment: You need to return the variables from the `setup` function so that they could be used during rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the variables from the `setup` function so that they can be accessed from within the template.

> If setup returns an object, the properties on the object can be
> accessed in the component's template, as well as the properties of the
> props passed into setup:

```
setup() {
    let data = ref([]);
    axios
      .get("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
      .then((res) => {
        data.value = res.data.bpi;
      });
      // return the data as an object
      return {
          data
      }
  }
```

Read more about this in the official vue [doc](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#usage-with-templates)

Comment: Thank you but the problem is still happening. console.log() it also doesn't work in setup(). Could the problem be "export default class HelloWorld extends Vue" that I used? In cmd, I created the project by selecting the properties myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `api` dir inside `src` folder and then inside `api` dir create a file api.ts and put this code

```
export async function callApi(endpoint :string, method :string){
    return await fetch(endpoint,{
        method:method,
        headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
    }).then(async response => {
        const resData = await response.json()
        if (!response.ok) {
            // do something to determine request is not okay
             resData.isSuccess = false
        }
        return resData
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("callApi in api.ts  err")
        console.log(error)
        throw error
    })
}
```

Go to you component and use this code

```
<template>
    <div  v-for="(item,i) in data.records" v-bind:key="i">
      {{ item.chartName}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import {onMounted,reactive} from "vue"
import {callApi} from "@/api/api"

export default{
    name:'MyComponent',
    setup() {

        const data = reactive({
            records: [],
        })

        onMounted( async() =>{
            getRecords()
        })

         const getRecords = async() => {
            let resData = await callApi('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json', 'GET')
            data.records = resData
        }

        return {
          data,
        }
    }
   }
</script>
enter code here
```

Comment: _callApi in api.ts err_ and _api.ts?de46:16 TypeError: Failed to fetch_ I got these errors. I added `mode: 'no-cors'` in fetch' header. But I got this error _Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input_